# Displaying certain div from external site on my site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am making a website and I'd like to display a portion of an external website seamlessly on my own. For example a certain div element. I understand this is not straightforward due to the same origin policy.. Is there a way to bypass this? For example dumping the website onto a local file and then loading it? Or screenshotting the website portion and linking to the image?

Comment: You can use CURL to get the content and a parser to interpret the content

Comment: 1) Iframe 2) Curl 3) get_file_content()

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
<?php
   $url = "http://www.bla.com";
   $page_all = file_get_contents($url); 

   preg_match('#<div class="hola">(.*)</div>#ms', $page_all, $div_array);


   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($div_array[0]);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**Note** php solution requires `allow_url_fopen` option **enabled** thanks @shiplu.mokadd.im

or by ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://bla.com',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(res) {
  var divcontent= $(res.responseText).find('#div_name').html();
    $('#blabla').html(divcontent);
  }
});
```

Comment: your php solution requires `allow_url_fopen` option enabled. Its not available all time

Comment: I think cross-site ajax requests will be blocked by the browser due to the difference in origin.

Comment: @Azriel yup because of same origin policy